# convert two vector<double> to form vector<complex<double>>

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have two vectors of type double and I want to combine them to make a complex vector.

```
vector<double> vReal;
vector<double> vImag;
```

How do I combine the above two to get

```
vector<complex<double>> vComp;
```

Can somebody please help me how do I do it?

Many Thanks.

Best Regards

Chintan

Answer (score 5):

```
    vComp.reserve(vReal.size());

    std::transform(
        begin(vReal), end(vReal), begin(vImag), 
        std::back_inserter(vComp), 
        [](double r, double i) { return std::complex<double>(r, i); });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [std::transform](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/), supplying a suitable `BinaryOperation`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < vReal.size(); ++i) {
  complex<double> iNum(vReal[i], vImag[i]);
  vComp.push_back(iNum);
}
```

Or am I missing something?

Perhaps also a check to make sure vReal and vImag are the same size otherwise you'll crash.

Comment: I much prefer this answer for simplicity. You could also do away with the temporary.

Answer (score 1):

If no support for C++11

```
std::complex<double> make_complex(double re, double im) {
    return std::complex<double>(re,im);
}

std::transform(vReal.begin(), vReal.end(), vImag.begin(), std::back_inserter(vComp), make_complex);
```